# TypeError after processing last row using apply with lambda using function returning multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, typeerror, apply

Here I am trying to find three different values of a sentence from that of every word it has and save them in the same dataframe in different columns for sentiment measurement. I am providing a list of words in each sentence to apply function sen_values() to find them. Here is the code:

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

valdf = pd.read_csv('/home/errvals.csv')
dfSentence = pd.read_csv('/home/data/answars.csv')
```

dfSentence has 360022 rows and
valdf has 13915 rows. The function:

```
def set_values(sen):
    senval1 = senval2 = senval3 = 0
    for w in sen:
        val1 = valdf.loc[valdf['Word'] == w,'v1'].values[0]
        val2 = valdf.loc[valdf['Word'] == w,'v2'].values[0]
        val3 = valdf.loc[valdf['Word'] == w,'v3'].values[0]

    senval1 = senval1 + val1
    senval2 = senval2 + val2
    senval3 = senval3 + val3

    return pd.Series([senval1, senval2, senval3])
```

The call:

```
dfSentence[['senval1', 'senval2', 'senval3']] = dfSentence["senwords"].apply(lambda sentence: set_values(sentence))
```

The error given is as follows in short:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 dfSentence[['senval1', 'senval2', 'senval3']] = dfTests["senwords"].apply(lambda sentense: set_values(sentense))


~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4141             # GH 25959 use pd.array instead of tolist
   4142             # so extension arrays can be used
-> 4143             return self._constructor_expanddim(pd_array(mapped), index=self.index)
   4144         else:
   4145             return self._constructor(mapped, index=self.index).__finalize__(

....
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()<ipython-input-41-7752fa37cc48> in <module>
```

The same problem is happening even after reducing the data size to 60 and even 20 percent of its original number of rows, but the code is running well with 100-500 rows
This does not occur when set_values is returning a single value. I am eager to know what makes this problem so difficult and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

==============================================

Following Furas, the variable sen in the function contains values as given below:

```
[shouted][younger][brother][always][afraid][called][loudly]
```

This is the contents that is coming from the last sentence of the dataset.
However I changed my code in the following way.
The function:

```
def set_values(sen):
    senval1 = senval2 = senval3 = 0
    for w in sen:
        val1 = valdf.loc[valdf['Word'] == w,'v1'].values[0]
            val2 = valdf.loc[valdf['Word'] == w,'v2'].values[0]
            val3 = valdf.loc[valdf['Word'] == w,'v3'].values[0]
        
        senval1 = senval1 + val1
        senval2 = senval2 + val2
        senval3 = senval3 + val3

        return str(senval1)+' '+str(senval2)+' '+str(senval3)
```

The call:

```
dfSentence["sen_vals"] = dfSentence["senwords"].apply(lambda sentense: set_values(sentence))
```

... to get the three values at one go for each sentence. This solves the problem for now. But it's still unclear what is the problem while returning multiple values for a large dataset. Thank you for your kind and serious attention to solving the problem.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: better put example data directly in question as text `DataFrame(....)` so we could simply copy and run it - to see problem

Comment: I am facing the problem only when processing the last sentence in each cases. @furas

Comment: I will repeat - use `print()` to see what values you have in variables and which code is execute. maybe you have wrong values in last sentence. We can't see your data, we can't run your code - you have to debug problem on your own.

Comment: Formatted the code as pointed out @furus

Comment: Did it. The problem is happening irrespective of whatever is the last sentence

Comment: To get the values of all the variables, it will take almost 5-6 hours. Can post only after all the variables reach their final state.

Comment: I see `senval_1 = senval1 + val1` but `senval_1` is never used.  Is this the real code? Please copy and paste, we can't help with a badly transcribed version unfortunately.  (And for `senval2 = senval2 + val2` please use `senval2 += val2` to do everyone a favour.)

Comment: The '_' has somehow been added mistakenly. That cannot be the cause of errors like this.

Comment: you can also use `try/except` to catch error and write information in file or log (using module `logging`). This way it can run long time and write all wrong values in file/log

Comment: @furas  Thanks. Did it: 
`try: 
return pd.Series([stanza_valence, stanza_arousal, stanza_dominance]) 
except TypeError: print("Type error happened") 
except: print("something else happened")` 
But no exception occurred from inside the function or my code. The problem is coming from apply() itself as the given error msg shows. And still the problem is coming after six hours of running right after the last sentence whatever it is.

Comment: and this is why you could use `print()` to see for what valuse in `set_values()` it gives this error. And maybe you should run it only for few last senteces. maybe all problem is only with last values.

Comment: Thanks, @furas, Originally the function is long and complicated as a large number of variables and values are there. Whenever I am running this with nearly a minimum of 80,000 rows from anywhere in the data containing almost 4 lakh rows, this problem is shown.  It's not being possible to get to see values for all the rows, even for last ones in any case.